# A suitable feature vector for images

Tags: clustering, feature-extraction

I have a set of images of various products from different websites. I would like to cluster the images based on the product shown in the image. How can I generate a suitable feature vector for an image for this purpose? I just need to know how to generate a feature vector given an image. I tried NetVLAD, but it is very slow. I would like something that is fast and gives high accuracy for clustering in the scenario I have described. Please help me.

Comment: You should add more info about your dataset (size, number of samples, number of desired clusters). You should also explain what do you mean by slow/fast and high accuracy. These things mainly depend on your computational limitations...

Comment: There are 282,082 images with a total size of almost 60 GB.  I don't have a desired number of clusters. I want an accuracy of better than 80%. I want it to be fast enough to run on a workstation in a couple of days (at most).

Comment: Can someone help me with this??

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a pre-trained deep learning model for object detection. It would be fast because it would only do the prediction / forward-pass.

For example, PyTorch has out-of-the-box [object detection models](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#object-detection-instance-segmentation-and-person-keypoint-detection).

Answer (score 0):

Feature extraction is basically reducing the amount of resources required to describe a large set of data. Analysis with a large number of variables (like images) generally requires a big amounts of memory and computation power.
You can start from the simplest and slowly work your way up (in computational requirements) until you reach your desired accuracy.

Start from:

**ORB** (oriented FAST, rotated robust independent features) -> **SURF** (speed up robust feature) -> **SIFT** (scale invariant feature transform) -> **OverFeat** (Convolutional Network) -> **vgg16** ... (There are many more, any neural network model can be used for this)

Comment: I would like to try out ORB. But, I am facing a difficulty. Given two different images, how do I find the distance between them using ORB features??